# Angular Material SnackBar showing without styles

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-material

I am trying to implement a [Angular Material SnackBar](https://material.angular.io/components/snack-bar/api) and it is rendering, but without proper styles.

My code:

**notification-snack-bar.component.html**

```
<div class="notification-snack-bar-container flex">
  <div>
    <span class="mat-warn-color"
      >An Error Occurred: {{ message }}<br /><span *ngIf="timerCount > 0"
        >Timer: {{ timerCount }}</span
      ></span
    ><br /><span>See the console for the full error.</span>
  </div>
  <button mat-button color="accent" (click)="dismiss()">{{ action }}</button>
</div>
```

**notification-snack-bar.component.ts**

```
import { Component, Inject } from '@angular/core';
import { MAT_SNACK_BAR_DATA, MatSnackBar } from '@angular/material/snack-bar';
import { NotificationService } from './notification.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-notification-snack-bar',
  templateUrl: 'notification-snack-bar.component.html',
  styles: [
    `
      .flex {
        justify-content: space-between;
        align-items: center;
      }
      .notification-snack-bar-container > div {
        overflow: hidden;
      }
      span {
        width: 100%;
        display: inline-block;
      }
      span > span {
        padding: 0;
      }
      button {
        padding: 0;
      }
    `,
  ],
})
export class NotificationSnackBarComponent {
  // set the default values
  public action = 'dismiss';
  public interval: any = null;
  public message = 'Unknown error...';

  // track the time for the timer
  public timerCount = 0;

  constructor(
    @Inject(MAT_SNACK_BAR_DATA) public data: any,
    public snackBar: MatSnackBar,
    private notificationService: NotificationService,
  ) {
    // load the properties from the data passed in
    // if the data.message is a string -> pass it through
    // else if the data.message is an object and it has the .message property -> pass it through
    // else indicate an unknown error
    console.log(data)
    this.message =
      typeof data.message === 'string'
        ? data.message
        : typeof data.message === 'object' && data.message.message
          ? data.message.message
          : 'Unknown Error...';
    this.action = data.action ? data.action : 'dismiss';
  }

  /**
   * start a timer for the given amount of seconds
   * @param timerDuration: number
   */
  startTimer(timerDuration: number) {
    this.timerCount = timerDuration;
    this.interval = setInterval(() => {
      if (this.timerCount > 0) {
        this.timerCount--;
      } else {
        this.timerCount = 60;
      }
    }, 1000);
  }

  // close the snack bar
  dismiss(): void {
    // indicate on the service that the error is being closed
    this.notificationService.errorBeingDisplayed = false;
    // dismiss the actual snack bar
    this.snackBar._openedSnackBarRef!.dismiss();
  }
}
```

**header.component.ts** (where the SnackBar component is called)

```
import { Component, OnInit, NgZone } from '@angular/core';
import { MatSnackBar } from '@angular/material/snack-bar';
import { NotificationService } from '../notification/notification.service';
import { NotificationSnackBarComponent } from '../notification/notification-snack-bar.component';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-header',
  templateUrl: './header.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./header.component.scss'],
})
export class HeaderComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(
    private snackBar: MatSnackBar,
    private notificationService: NotificationService,
    private zone: NgZone,


  ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.notificationService.displayError$.subscribe((error) => {
      // Load the given component into the snack-bar.
      this.zone.run(() => {
        this.snackBar.openFromComponent(NotificationSnackBarComponent, {
          data: {
            message: error,
          },
        });
      });
    });
  }
}
```

**angular.json**
[image]

And this is what renders:
[image]
[image]

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Running  `ng add @angular/material` seemed to this this for me

Answer (score 0):

Try adding ::ng-deep to your css:

```
::ng-deep {

      .flex {
        justify-content: space-between;
        align-items: center;
      }
      .notification-snack-bar-container > div {
        overflow: hidden;
      }
      span {
        width: 100%;
        display: inline-block;
      }
      span > span {
        padding: 0;
      }
      button {
        padding: 0;
      }
}
```

Comment: I am not sure that will help - considering it doesn't seem like the Angular Material theme styles themselves are loading.